# Why am I getting an error using 'set' in Python?

Tags: python, set

```
s = set('ABC')
s.add('z')
s.update('BCD')
s.remove('DEF') # error here
s -= set('DEFG')
```

Comment: @zjm1126:  please include traceback next time.

Comment: i'm sorry,what is the 'traceback '???

Comment: >>> s.remove('DEF')
`Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
KeyError: 'DEF'`

Comment: @zjm1126:  Traceback is the actual error message you actually get when you actually run this in Python.  It shows the lines of code and "traces the error back" from the thing that failed to the thing that initiated execution.
@Adam Bernier: It helps to update the question rather than add more hard-to-read comments.  You may not have enough reputation.  In which case, it may be better to wait for the author to learn how to do it.

Comment: @S.Lott: point well taken. My rationale for the hard-to-read comment is the OP's difficulties with English.

Answer (score 18, accepted):

As others pointed out, `'DEF'`, the set member you're trying to remove, is **not** a member of the set, and `remove`, per [the docs](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set.remove#set.remove), is specified as "Raises KeyError if elem is not contained in the set.".

If you want "missing element" to mean a silent no=op instead, just use [discard](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html?highlight=set.remove#set.discard) instead of `remove`: that's **the** crucial difference between the `discard` and `remove` methods of sets, and the very reason they both need to exist!

Comment: Just curious Why python chooses `KeyError` to raise other than any other error?

Comment: @dlmeetei set always stores data as unique keys and when we perform operations, it searches using those keys. So, if a key is not found it'll throw `KeyError`.

Answer (score 2):

The argument to [`set.remove()`](http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html#set.remove) must be a set member.

`'DEF'` is not a member of your set. `'D'` is.

Answer (score 0):

From http://docs.python.org/library/stdtypes.html :

> remove(elem)
>
> Remove element elem from the set. Raises KeyError if elem is not contained in the set.

'DEF' is not in the set

Answer (score 0):

Do you expect `'DEF'` to be treated as an **element** or a **set**?

In the latter case use `s.difference_update('DEF')`.

Comment: It does not matter how he wants them to be treated, the problem is that 'EF' do not exist in the set, hence the error message.

Comment: Disagreed. "You are calling the wrong method for this argument" is also a valid answer to the question. Given that the author is using strings as sets, it is valid to suspect that he needs `difference_update()` here.